# JSF Currency mapped as NUMBER on the database

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I'm using Seam 2.2.2, JSF Mojarra 1.2_13-b01-FCS, JBoss 5.1.0 Server.

I have an Oracle table with three columns specified as type NUMBER.  The generated hibernate mapping has mapped those columns in the entity class as java.math.BigDecimal.  These are currency values, and BigDecimal seems to be the preferred way of storing and calculating those values in Java.

I'm trying to use the number converter to use the values on screen as currency in an h:inputText and h:outputText.  Works fine until I try to update one of those values, when java throws an Exception:

EquipItemEdit.xhtml value="#{equipItemHome.instance.cost}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

My entity is mapped like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EQUIP_ITEM")
public class EquipItem implements java.io.Serializable {
  ...

    private BigDecimal cost;
  ...

        @Column(name = "COST", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getCost() {
        return this.cost;
    }

    public void setCost(BigDecimal cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

  ...
}
```

Table definition in the database

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIP_ITEM
(
  EQUIP_ID      NUMBER,
  COUNTER       NUMBER,
  ITEM          VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  ACQADC        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  COG           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  COST          NUMBER,
  NOMENC        VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
  QUA_AUTH      NUMBER,
    ...
)
```

And how the field is mapped on the JSP:

```
...
<h:inputText id="cost"
 styleClass="value"
          value="#{equipItemHome.instance.cost}"
           size="15">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" locale="en_US"/>                                        
</h:inputText>
...
```

Any suggestions, or can someone point me to the right way to handle this data type?

---

For now to get things working I wrote my own converter.  Haven't done much testing yet, and hoping someone can show me how to get the JSF built-in converter working for this.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.intercept.BypassInterceptors;

@Name("usDollarsConverter")
@BypassInterceptors
@org.jboss.seam.annotations.faces.Converter
public class UsDollarsConverter implements javax.faces.convert.Converter, Serializable {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String     string) {
        if(string == null) {
            return null;
        }       

        try {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);          
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);         
            Object value = nf.parse(string);
            if(value instanceof Double) {
                value = new BigDecimal((Double)value);
            } else if(value instanceof Long) {
                value = new BigDecimal((Long) value);
            }
            return value;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }           

    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(value instanceof Double) {
            value = new BigDecimal((Double)value);
        } else if(value instanceof Long) {
            value = new BigDecimal((Long) value);
        }



        if(value instanceof BigDecimal) {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);          
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);         
            return nf.format(((BigDecimal)value).doubleValue());            
        }

        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("UsDollarsConverter requires a type java.math.BigDecimal, will not work with " +     value.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite its name, `<f:convertNumber/>` will not convert `BigDecimal`... if you check the Javadoc for `javax.faces.convert.NumberConverter`, it tells that it will produce either a `Long` (for integral numbers) or a `Double`. This is because, to parse BigDecimals with a NumberFormat, you need to set a flag `setParseBigDecimal(true)`, otherwise the NumberFormat object only produces doubles.

JSF does provide a separate converter for BigDecimals (aptly named `javax.faces.BigDecimal`), instead of `<f:convertNumber/>` use:

`<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal" />`

And the conversion will work. This converter however is not as flexible as `<f:convertNumber/>`, you cannot set the pattern or use different locales, among other things. Thus, most people just write their own converter implementation.